# How can i sign something or provide proof-of-identity for windows user?

Tags: winapi

I have an application where i want to verify that a request is coming from a user that's currently signed-in to (A) a particular Domain or is (B) a particular Microsoft 365 user.

Can I call a windows api function of some kind to get a token or some other proof of access that I can user to verify the identity of the user?

For example someone claims to be bob@bob.com signed into M365... how can they provide proof that they are?  OR \mydomain\bob

And then is there an API for verifying that proof with M365 or the domain server?

What I don't want is an already-signed-in-user to have to type a username and password in anywhere, but everything i see leads to that.

This is something like "single signon" from what I can tell.

I have a server that's receiving requests from a desktop application of a signed-in user.   Just want to be sure it's the right user.

Comment: *"I have a sneaking suspicion I'm just googling the wrong terms."* - You are probably looking for "Single Sign-On". I don't know the exact terminology Microsoft have agreed on this week, though.

Comment: *request is coming from* - what request ? where verify ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, pretty sure what I need are [SSPI functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-initializesecuritycontexta).

InitializeSecurityContextA : Application on the client side of a connection sends credentials to the server by using the SSPI function

AcceptSecurityContext :  lets the server component of a transport application establish a security context between the server and a remote client.